# Changing the initial scene in spritekit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

**Aim:**

To load the scene in Instructions1.swift file as the first scene of the game.

**What I did :**

So I created 2 new files in my project : Instructions1.sks and Instructions1.swift

Then in GameViewController.swift , I changed the viewDidLoad as follows :

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("Instructions1") as? GameScene
        {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

However when I load the game, it goes straight to GameScene.swift. I also wrote 'Instructions1' under the Custom Class for  Instructions1.sks . Still no luck unfortunately!

Would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `if let scene = Instructions1(fileNamed:"Instructions1")`? Also, if `Instructions1` is a scene, you probably want to be descriptive and name it `Instructions1Scene`. The 1 is suspect as well, but you probably have a reason.

Comment: Unfortunately that is giving compilation error : "Use of unresolved identifier 'InstructionsOne" and is highlighting the InstructionsOne in if let scene = InstructionsOne.unarchiveFromFile........

Thanks!

Comment: What Ben said should work, replace all GameScene with Instruction1

Comment: @BenKane , I have done a search and  replace and this is my new code :

http://pastebin.com/aMpZdDuG

Unfortunately it still doesn't work and I get this compilation error :

http://s32.postimg.org/kdfd6xbsl/Screen_Shot_2016_04_27_at_21_08_48.png

Any other advise please? 

Thanks!!

Comment: You still haven't tried what I suggested, though. What I suggested is the updated way to do it. You're using an old approach. `if let scene = InstructionsOne.unarchiveFromFile` isn't close to `if let scene = Instructions1(fileNamed:"Instructions1")`. Please try what I suggested again

Comment: Hi @BenKane,

So I tried if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"Instructions1") which doesn't do anything. Then I tried what you suggested and it gives me this error: http://s32.postimg.org/xqgy77zw5/Screen_Shot_2016_04_27_at_22_43_13.png
 Thanks!!

Comment: Did you change your class name? I assumed your class was the same as the file name. You want `ClassName(fileNamed: "SKSFileName")`.

Comment: Change it where? Yes I did create2 new files in my project : Instructions1.sks and Instructions1.swift.

Also I noticed something very strange. As I type in GameScene, it comes up in the auto fill like this to show that it is a class:
http://s32.postimg.org/u8mgl4yt1/Screen_Shot_2016_04_27_at_22_54_36.png

However Instructions1 doesnt :

http://s32.postimg.org/taa8d7tx1/Screen_Shot_2016_04_27_at_22_55_01.png

Does that give you any pointers?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you put anything inside of `Instructions1.swift`? It'll just be an empty file by default. You need to at least put `class Instructions1: SKScene { }` inside the file.

Comment: I've got this:

http://pastebin.com/667gBfKA

Comment: Make the class name Instructions1.

Comment: I apologise for that stupidity. I changed that but I still get this error in the viewcontroller:
http://s32.postimg.org/cadix43ed/main_error.png

Comment: @BenKane , I get a feeling that Instructions1.swift is not being registered as a class. That is why it is not coming up in the auto fill.

Comment: Is there a way to test that by calling Instructions1, as soon as GameScene loads? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the name of the scene that you're loading up. Also using the **init(fileNamed:)** initializer is a go-to for me when loading a SKScene from a file.

Hopefully this helps!

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = Instructions1(fileNamed:"Instructions1")
    {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ryan Temple,
Thanks for the reply. I get this compilation error : http://s32.postimg.org/5tij66dat/Screen_Shot_2016_04_28_at_20_41_34.png

As if 'Instructions1' in the line if let scene = Instructions1 is not recognised as a class at all!

Thanks!!

Comment: @user3369038 is Instructions1.swift class in your project directory and is the class properly initialized?

Comment: I think so. I am still learning things as I go along by watching tutorials online and is the first time I am creating a new class /scene :

This is the project structure :
http://s32.postimg.org/pftk38u6t/Screen_Shot_2016_04_28_at_20_49_41.png

This is the class itself :
http://s32.postimg.org/5j0yg4yj9/Screen_Shot_2016_04_28_at_20_50_25.png

Comment: @user3369038 Heres what I suggest you do because there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code. Create a new project and recreate it all (if its not to much to copy over). This may eliminate the problem!